# Hiding page's black border in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is it possible to make page's black border hidden in indesign?  ( As we can hide art board in illustrator)  I am not comfortable with that thin black border around my design when designing web pages...

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That border defines the InDesign page, and it's not configurable.

When using InDesign to design web pages, though, you can use this to your advantage by defining a document size that represents a browser window rather than just the web page. Drag out or create (`Layout > Create Guides`) guides to define your page within that larger document page and build the web page within them. You can easily hide and show guides by toggling between Normal and Preview modes or using the keyboard shortcut Ctl/Cmd-; to hide just the guides, so you have them when you need them and they disappear when you don't.

Using this approach, you can place your website background under the page design for a much better visual representation of the final look of the site.

This is a very common practice when building site mockups in Photoshop or Illustrator, too, for the same reason.